# Overlapping matches with regex for ngrams

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string and need to use regex.

```
"hello COMMA the matche's roll over matche's or the expression for details PCRE flavors of regex are supported here"
```

and i want to find bi and trigrams of it. So focusing on bigrams it should pull

```
hello COMMA
COMMA the
the matche's
etc
```

Ive written this regex to do that but its not grabbing the overlapping results.

```
[\w'-]+ [\w'-]+
```

it will only grab

```
hello COMMA
the matches
etc
```

when i wrap it in ?= like this it grabs all sorts of trash now. What am I missing?

```
(?=([\w'-]+ [\w'-]+))
```

also the overlap=True thing doesnt work for me for somereason

Comment: Try `(?=(?<!\S)(\w+(?:['-]\w+)*(?:\s+\w+(?:['-]\w+)*))(?!\S))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/doyYXZ/1)

Comment: In Ruby this can be done as follows for an *n-gram*. If `str = "hello COMMA ... supported here"` and `n = 3` (a trigram), then `str.split.each_cons(n).map { |a| a.join(' ') } #=> ["hello COMMA the", "COMMA the matche's", "the matche's roll",...]`. I expect this can be done in Python using-Python equivalent methods for Ruby's [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split), [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regular expressions for text processing. There is the package NLTK that was specifically designed for that job:

```
import nltk
text = "hello COMMA the matche's roll over ..."
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
list(nltk.bigrams(words))
# [('hello', 'COMMA'), ('COMMA', 'the'), ('the', 'matche'),...]
list(nltk.trigrams(words))
#[('hello', 'COMMA', 'the'), ('COMMA', 'the', 'matche'), ...]
```

Comment: that is slick but im required to use regex for this, ive update the op to say that.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

str = "hello COMMA the matche's roll over matche's or the expression for details PCRE flavors of regex are supported here"

matches = re.finditer(r'\S+\s(?=(\S+))', str)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(0) + match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
hello COMMA
COMMA the
the matche's
matche's roll
[snipped]
```

The regex `(?=(\S+))` includes a capture group within the positive lookahead assertion.
It assigns `match.group(1)` to the matched substring without moving the position forward thanks to the zero-width matching.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression below is a generalisation and simplification of the regex suggested in a comment on the question by @Wiktor. Wiktor's solution was for 2-grams (or bigrams). This solution is for 3-grams (or trigrams). For n-grams, where `n` is a variable, replace `{2}` with `{#{n-1}}`.

First assume that the string contains only word characters and whitespace. The following regex can then be used to extract the trigrams:

```
(?=(?<!\S)(\w+(?:\s+\w+){2}))
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/7RkjFs/4/)

The regex can be broken down as follows:

```
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead   
  (?<!        # begin a negative lookbehind
    \S        # match a a non-whitespace char
  )           # end the negative lookbehind
  (           # begin capture group 1
    \w+       # match 1+ word chars
    (?:       # begin a non-capture group
      \s+\w+  # match 1+ whitespace chars followed by 1+ word chars
    )         # end non-capture group
    {1,2}     # execute the non-capture group 1-2 times 
  )           # end capture group
)             # end positive lookahead
```

If, as in the example, the string may also contain apostrophes within words (but not at the beginning or end of a word), each token `\w+` above can be replaced with `\w+(?:[']\w+)*` to obtain:

```
(?=(?<!\S)((?:\w+(?:[']\w+)*(?:\s+\w+(?:[']\w+)*){1,2})))
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/aLPZTr/2/)

The regex quickly breaks down, however, if too much is asked for the possible numbers and locations of certain characters.

This is an example of a situation where a regex should *not* be used, as the desired array can be produced much more easily with other tools. It is a useful exercise, however, as it does sharpens one's facility with regular expressions.